# problema al ejecutar mi codigo como . exe

Tags: c++

Cuando abro mi programa hecho en c++ como archivo .exe desde el escritorio de mi ordenador , me permite darle los datos que pido según el código, pero no me muestra el resultado. Eso solo pasa cuando accedo a el sin el editor de código, cuando lo uso y lo ejecuto desde allí, el programa funciona correctamente (uso el editor dev c++).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin ver tu programa o donde ocurre el error va a ser dificil ayudarte...

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que entendí por tu pregunta eso ocurre porque el programa muestra el resultado y luego acaba cerrándose por lo que no da tiempo a que puedas ver el resultado, para solucionar esto tienes dos opciones:

Opción 1:

usar cin.get() al final de tu código (antes del return 0 del final del programa)

Opción 2:

(incluyendo conio.h (#include<conio.h>)

usar getch(); antes del return 0

de cualquiera de las dos maneras el programa te pedirá que pulses una tecla antes de terminar su ejecución, (con getch() da igual la tecla pero si usas cin.get() tendrá que ser el enter obligatoriamente).

Si no es la respuesta que esperabas necesitaríamos el código para ver posibles fallos.